# Cannot read property 'getIosIdForVendorAsync' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-build

I am creating an expo build with this command:

`eas build --profile development --platform ios`

This creates the build that I can install and everything works properly (deviceIds are added and everything goes well) . The Eas build shows correctly too.

When I open the app in my iPhone 14 I get this error:

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIosIdForVendorAsync' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Which shows 1000 plus times (in a loop). Here is my current app.json where bundleid is my unique identifier of apple (I've removed it it's on the bundleidentifier):

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "ewwapp",
    "name": "eww",
    "slug": "eww",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "bundleid.com.eww.app",
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.eww.app",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "my project id"
      }
    },
    "owner": "eww-app"
  }
}
```

And this is my eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.8.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium",
        "enterpriseProvisioning": "universal"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Any suggestion?

[image]

I was trying to create a build of my expo app on iOS

Answer (score 1):

I was running another process so closing all my other terminals worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error, however I had an error higher up in the error stack which was named:

```
TypeError: 0, _expoModulesCore.requireOptionalNativeModule is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
```

It ended up being a library compatibility issue with expo dependencies.

Running `npx expo install --fix` and working through the issues ended up resolving this problem for me.